# Pandas how to avoid apply in groupby nlargest n

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas apply is generally recommended not to be used. I have a situation here where I am interested if there are more efficient alternatives to the option of apply.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1990,1990,1990,1992,1992,1992,1992,1993,1993,1993],
                   'item': list('abcdefghij'),
                  'value': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,990]})
df
```

I would like to get top 2 values for each year.

```
df.groupby('year')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).reset_index()
```

Is there any alternative to this? Anything whether longer lines of codes or whatever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort_values` the do with `tail`

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby('year').tail(2) # when need continue position 
Out[199]: 
   year item  value
1  1990    b    200
2  1990    c    300
5  1992    f    600
6  1992    g    700
8  1993    i    900
9  1993    j    990
```

Or

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby('year',as_index=False).nth([-2,-1])#more flexible you can pick 1,-1 
Out[202]: 
   year item  value
1  1990    b    200
2  1990    c    300
5  1992    f    600
6  1992    g    700
8  1993    i    900
9  1993    j    990
```

---

Timing

```
%timeit df.sort_values('value').groupby('year').tail(2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 894 µs per loop
%timeit df.groupby('year')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.76 ms per loop
```

Comment: do we have certainty that this approach is more efficient than `apply`?

Comment: @Yuca the output is different , apply do not include the item column , also change the order of columns

Comment: agree, just wondering if this is more efficient than using apply since that's also what the OP asked. Not saying there's anything wrong with the answer, just curious

Comment: @Yuca check the timing :-)

Answer (score 0):

**When we have NaNs**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': list('abcdefghijk'),
                   'year': [1990,1990,1990,1992,1992,1992,1992,1993,1993,1993,1993],
                   'value':[10 , 11  ,12  ,20  ,21  ,22  ,23  ,30  ,31  ,32  ,np.nan]})
print(df)
   item  year  value
0     a  1990   10.0
1     b  1990   11.0
2     c  1990   12.0
3     d  1992   20.0
4     e  1992   21.0
5     f  1992   22.0
6     g  1992   23.0
7     h  1993   30.0
8     i  1993   31.0
9     j  1993   32.0
10    k  1993    NaN
```

## Using apply (SLOW)

```
top2 = df.groupby('year')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).reset_index(level=0)
print(df.loc[top2.index])
# time: 2.96ms

  item  year  value
2    c  1990   12.0
1    b  1990   11.0
6    g  1992   23.0
5    f  1992   22.0
9    j  1993   32.0
8    i  1993   31.0
```

## Without using apply (FASTER)

```
print(df.dropna(subset=['value']).sort_values('value').groupby('year').tail(2))
# time: 2.01ms

  item  year  value
1    b  1990   11.0
2    c  1990   12.0
5    f  1992   22.0
6    g  1992   23.0
8    i  1993   31.0
9    j  1993   32.0
```